# jeasyui: how to get queryparams in another page by clientside

Tags: jquery-easyui

jeasyui: how to get queryparams in another page by clientside
page 1(root.html):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    async: true,
    url: "/ashx/product/root.ashx",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (res) {
        var o = $('#tb');
        for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            o.tabs('add', {
                title: res[i].Name + '-' + res[i].PkId,
                href: '/html/usr/node.html', queryParams: { 'id': res[i].id }
            });
            o.tabs('select', 0);
        }
    }
});
```

page 2(node.html):

```
<script>
    // how to get queryParams from page root.html here in javascript.
    alert();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

JQUERY

```js
$.ajax({
     url:"node.html.html",
     dataType: 'jsonp', 
     success:function(json){
         alert("Success");
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error Message");
     }      
});
```

node.html  ( note im using php )

```
<?php
$arr = array("param1",
             "param2",
             array("param3","param4"));
$arr['name'] = "response";
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```